# How to make QGIS for MacOS Python version work from the command line?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, macos

I am trying to set up QGIS' Python installation that ships with it for MacOS X for use outside of QGIS. I have found little resources for this for QGIS 3.x on MacOS, the only really helpful resource so far has been [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mkpaa/e8a5b349d02c6677e38d9ac505019312). I have set up pyenv to manage QGIS' Python version along with my homebrew install successfully.

Importing QGIS works fine, however, I can't seem to open a QGIS instance from the command line:

```py
>>> from qgis.core import *
>>> from qgis.gui import *
>>> app = QgsApplication([], True)
>>> app.initQgis()
```

produces:

```bsh
[1]    54552 segmentation fault  python3
```

In my `~/.zshrc` I have specified the following variables:

```bsh
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python 
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python/lib-dynload
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/python/site-packages
export QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/
export GDAL_DATA=/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/Resources/gdal/
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

I am on MacOS 10.15.7 using QGIS-LTR (3.16)